# Regular expressions: How to combine AND & OR operators

Tags: regex

I'm currently trying to perform a single regular expression which combine AND / OR operators but can't find a way to deal with it.
I'm using the PHP PCRE regex engine.

I've a text and I want to check the matching regarding rules which are allowing / disallowing words.

Example :

Rule `allow`: I want all to allow text which contains `some`

Rule `disallow`: I want to disallow if the text contains `some page`

Text 1: I found some trick.

Text 2: I found some pages in the book.

For the moment I'm computing a unique regex to check if the text does not match :

```
//staring with not allowing
//continue with disallowing
/^(?=(?!(some.*)))(?=(some page)).*$/
```

This is my problem, if the allow rule contains the disallow rule, I can't get a valid regex. This never match.

I've checked with other regex operators but can't found a valid way to build my pattern.

I want to generate a unique regex here to push the lines of the regex capabilities (I know for the moment :)).

This process perfectly works when the allow does not contains the disallow :

Rule `allow`: I want to allow if the text contains `some page`

Rule `disallow`: I want to disallow is the text which contains `some`

In this order it works...

Comment: it work fine for me .*some(?!\spage).* [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/sI2lB8/3)

Comment: Of course the missing part of my question... I'm using PHP PCRE engine.

Comment: @KiraCrafter I can't compile the 2 different rules in a simpler one here. I must deal with the allow part and the disallow part to perform the match...

Comment: @shulard sounds like you shouldn't be using regex then

Comment: @bobblebubble Interesting answer, it works on my example. Can you explain how ?
Is it possible to use it with more complex rules (multiple allow / disallow) ?

Comment: @KiraCrafter Maybe I'll choose to use another solution than regex but I'm sure I can do this with regex :)

Comment: @bobblebubble I think you are right :) I'm going to find why and submit an answer here (or you can if you want :)).

Comment: Probably you wanted [like this](https://regex101.com/r/yX7lW2/1): `^(?!.*?some page).*?some.*$` similar first comment but easier for being computed.

Comment: [This was my other regex](https://regex101.com/r/yH1qQ2/1) where I thought I misunderstood: `^(?:.*?some page.*|(?!.*some).+)$`

Comment: It seems to work only in a way where allow contains disallow. But it doesn't work in the reverse way : `^(?!.*?some).*?some page.*$`
The first part black list the second... Maybe it's not possible to deal with it in a single regex...

Comment: Instead of "allow", do you perhaps mean "require"?  The regex `.*` *allows* `some`, just like it allows everything else.

Comment: I re-read your question several times, and I do not understand what you are trying to do. I am sure there is a logical error somewhere. Note that a text should not match if you allow "some page" but disallow "some" - it is only logical.

Comment: Indeed, the question is not easy to understand. I try to apply a black list + white list rules system on a text. If the text match the regex, black list wins, if not it's an allowed one.
So the rules can be allow `some` but disallow `some page`. The rules are defined at user level...

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use a negative lookahead

```
some(?! text)
```

https://regex101.com/r/bA7eV2/3